# Unable to understand why Compiler asking for reference to a class library even in case of Late Binding

Tags: vb.net

There are three code pieces, A, B and C. A and B are class libraries and C is an executable file. Part A is saved as MyMathsLibrary.dll, B as FactoryMathsLibrary.dll. C references B and B references A. C does not reference A.

```
Public Class MathOperations 'Part A
    Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
        Return (a + b)
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Imports MyMathsLibrary 'Part B
Public Class Factory
    Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations
        Return New MathOperations()
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Imports FactoryMathsLibrary 'Part C
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a, b As Integer
        Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()
        'Error comes on the right hand side of the = sign in the above statement
        Console.Write("Enter 1st value: ")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter 2nd value: ")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", m.ADD(a, b))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Question:
In the above code structure I am getting an error in the right hand side of the equal to sign in the statement: `Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()`. That is the red squiggly line appears under `Factory.createMathsObject`. I am not understanding the reason behind this error which reads: “*Reference required to assembly MyMathsLibrary….containing the type MathOperations…*”
In this case, the method `Factory.createMathsObject()` returns an instance of specific type namely the class `MathOperations`. However, that instance is Late Bound to the variable “m” as “m” is of OBJECT type. Now if there is late-binding the compiler should not be checking at compile-time what m can access in the object that it points to. **If that check is not happening why this error? Why does the compiler wants me to add the reference to `MyMathsLibrary`?**

Another observation is that keeping everything else unchanged, if I change the statement `Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations` in part B of the project to `Shared Function createMathsObject() As Object`, the above discussed error goes away and the code works fine. So changing the return type of the function in part B to OBJECT makes the compiler to  not ask for the reference to MyMathsLibrary. **Can someone pls explain why this is happening?**

I have a feeling that the explanation involves how late binding works but I am unable to apply the concept to explain the above observations. Pls help.

Comment: This: `Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()` is not late binding, that's a widening cast. This: `m.ADD(a, b)` is *late*. -- Is this just a curiosity? Otherwise, why did you use `Object` there?

Comment: There is a possible boxing conversion if the function returns a value type value.  Not code you have to write, but the compiler does to generate correct IL.  It can only do so accurately when it knows exactly what MathOperations looks like, could be an enum or Structure for example, and that requires the assembly that defines it.  If you change the return type to Object then that boxing conversion lives inside the assembly and doesn't have to be generated at the call site.

Comment: @jimi yes..purely out of curiosity. Was trying various things to better understand the concepts of Object type, late binding, referencing.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand the first part of your answer. Thank you for the that. But as for your last statement " ...change the return type to Object .... boxing conversion lives inside the assembly and doesn't have to be generated at the call site", i have two questions. Firstly, when the function in part B of the project returns OBJECT type, then why at all is there a boxing type conversion - asking because in such a case an object type value gets assigned to an OBJECT type variable? Why are you considering this as boxing conversion?

Comment: @HansPassant Secondly, if there is a boxing conversion even when the function in Part B returns OBJECT, which assembly does the boxing conversion live inside? Is it in the assembly corresponding to Part B (which has the function returning the OBJECT type) or Part A which calls the function in part B?

Comment: Then the compiler knows that no boxing conversion is actually needed.  If it is a Structure instead of a Class then the boxing conversion lives in the B assembly.  In the posted code, it is not knowing this for a fact that makes it ask for the reference.

Comment: @Hans Pasant Many thanks

Comment: @HansPassant For the sake of clarity, I rephrase my understanding. Pls tell if its correct. If the function in part B of the code does not return an object type, the compiler needs to ascertain the type of "MathOperations" and hence needs the reference to the assembly where the data type MathOperations reside. If the function in part B of the project returns an OBJECT type, there is no boxing involved and the code executes smoothly. Is this understanding right?

Comment: And a last question, in this case if the function in part B had returned a value type, then in the statement `Dim m as Object = Factory.createMathsObject()` in part C of the code, both boxing and widening would happen. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @Jimi You mentioned that `Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()` is not late binding but rather `m.Add` is late. However as per MSDN documentation, `an object is late bound when it is assigned to a variable declared to be of type Object`. And this is corroborated by the examples given in MSDN page where a statement like `xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` is given as an example of late binding. Here xlApp is a variable of object type. Is this not in contradiction to what you mentioned? The link to the MSDN page is found below:

Comment: @jimi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/

Comment: Have you ever noticed that event handlers pass the object that raised the event as the `sender` Object? Is that Late Binding? It's not, it's a cast: `Object` can be any type - any Reference Type in this case, so there's no boxing - and you just need to cast it back to its actual Type. This: `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` is a completely different condition, since the Type is unknown, it will be generated at run-time and any evaluation will be performed *later*. -- You can do the same thing: use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to create your `Factory` object, it will generate an Object Type.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your comment However I did not understand everything of what you wrote. But that is because my knowledge of how CreateObject (and COM in general) works is not very good. Let me read about it and come back if there are any questions. In the meantime, would be knowing any link that has good material on these topics.

Comment: Late binding is referring to a property or a method on something of type `Object` (other than the things that exist on `Object` themselves like `Equals`).  It requires reflection at runtime to check on the runtime type of the thing to ensure that the method or property actually exists, and with the correct signature.  Late binding requires working with things of type `Object`, but all instances where you work with things of type `Object` are not late binding.